# Why the symmetry is not $Pin(1,3)$ or $Pin(3,1)$ in condensed matter physics?

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, mathematical-physics, group-theory, spinors

In usual electron systems (or condensed matter physics), it is well known that $T^2=-1$ and $M^2=-1$, where $T$ and $M$ are time reversal and reflection along some axis. But in general, the symmetry of fermion should be one of two special double covers of $O(1,3)$ i.e. $Pin(1,3)$ or Pin(3,1). They have different sign of $T^2$ and $M^2$, for example, $Pin(3,1)$ has $T^2=-1$ and $M^2=1$, and $Pin(1,3)$ has $T^2=1$ and $M^2=-1$. But none of them are coincide with the usual case.

I’m wondering what is happening here?

Comment: Note that a condensed matter system usually has a preferred reference frame (=its rest frame) thereby breaking Lorentz symmetry.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes, but the restriction of O(1,3) to time reversal and reflection should not be changed unless we are considering quasiparticles.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer from myself.

The group $Pin(1,3)$ has group elements time reversal $T$ and reflection $M_i$ along 3 spatial axes such that $T^2=1$, $M_i^2=-1$ and $TM_i=-M_iT$, $i=x,y,z$. Similarly, $Pin(3,1)$ has $T^2=-1$, $M_i^2=1$ and $TM_i=-M_iT$

The quantum system with symmetry $Pin(1,3)$ or $Pin(3,1)$ is a complex representation of $Pin(1,3)$ or $Pin(3,1)$ with all group elements reversing the time axis antilinear, especially $T$ antilinear. The anilinear stuff is tricky, a better way to think about it is that we view the complex representation as a real representation but with an extra operator $i$ as the complex structre, and we also require $i$ to anticommute with all group elements reversing the time axis. Especially, $iT=-Ti$.

In usual consdensed matter physics, we actually require $T$ to commute with $M_i$, but the group $Pin(3,1)$ actually has $M_iT=-TM_i$. This can be fixed by redefinition of $M_i$ by $M_i'=iM_i$, so we have $M_i'T=TM_i'$ and $M_i'^2=-1$. In general, the redefinition make the restriction of $Pin(3,1)$ to its spatial part to be $Pin(0,3)$. This is why in the theory of fermionic topological matters, the symmetry is always $Pin_-(3)\cong Pin(0,3)$ (The symmetry is not $Pin(0,4)$ because $T$ commutes with $M_i$.).

By the way, it seems that the symmetry shouldn’t be $Pin(3,1)$ since we can’t change the sign of $T^2$ by redefinition of $T$ by $iT$.

As an example, consider the usual single spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ electron, on the spin degrees of freedom, $T=\sigma_y K$ and $M_x=\sigma_x$ which is the reflection along axis x, and $M_x'=i\sigma_x$. They satisfy the algebraic rules above. Similarly, reflection $M_y=\sigma_y$ along axis y also satisfies the rules.